# stdout stderr not captured from binary executed in singularity container

Tags: python, subprocess, pbs, singularity-container, apptainer

I have a complex HPC (openpbs 20.0.1, Ubuntu 18.04) workflow using a python subprocess to execute qsub which ultimately launches a singularity (3.9.9) container with the exec command to execute a binary with arguments. The complexity is driven by the needs of long-time existing workflows users are dependent on. Below is an exert.

For some unknown reason, the stdout & stderr is not being captured from the binary executed in the singularity container. The other redirects and verbose output from the singularity debug option are captured in the process-output.txt file.

Any thoughts why? Appreciate any input.

```
def _execute_pbs_jobs()

proc = Popen('ssh ${USER}@server_hostname /opt/pbs/bin/qsub', shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)

job_string = """
        #!/bin/bash -x
        #PBS -N %(name)s
        #PBS -l walltime=%(walltime)s
        #PBS -q workq
        ##PBS -j oe
        #PBS -k eod
        #PBS -l %(processors)s
        #PBS -l mem=%(memory)s
        #PBS -W umask=66

        PROCESS_OUTPUT="${JOBDIR}/process-output.txt"

        singularity --debug exec --env "${job_inst_env_variables}" --bind ${JOBDIR}/home:/home,%(context_dir)s,/mnt/pathfinder/logs,/mnt/pathfinder/logs/output/,/mnt/lustre/customers/:/mnt/pathfinder/lustre/customers /apps/containers/%(container_name)s %(binary)s "${JOB_ARGUMENTS_ARRAY[@]}" >> ${PROCESS_OUTPUT} 2>&1

""" % ({"job_names": job_names
                ,"walltime": walltime
                ,"processors": total_cores
                ,"context_dir": self.context_directory
                ,"binary": self.binary_name
                ,"name": ''.join(x for x in self.binary_name if x.isalnum())
                ,"arguments": arguments
                ,"env_vars": env_variables
                ,"inst_env_variables": inst_env_variables
                ,"memory": memory
                ,"num_jobs": self.get_instance_count()
                ,"date_string": exec_date.strftime("%Y.%m.%d.%a.%H.%M.%S")
                ,"qsub_args": qsub_arguments
                ,"container_name": self.container_image_name
                ,"debug_mode": debug_mode_arg
                })

        # Send job_string to qsub
        if (sys.version_info > (3, 0)):
            proc.stdin.write(job_string.encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            proc.stdin.write(job_string)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

return(stdout.rstrip())
```

Comment: Writing a post often creates more thoughts. I just realized that in the specific case I'm dealing with, the user is passing a python script as the executable. This particular python script uses a print statement to output what the user is interested in. 

When running the python script locally at a small scale. The output is printed to terminal with the print statement. I'm thinking the print statement may need to be replaced with sys.stdout.write